# MS Access SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions

I am new to SQL and attempting to display a max value from a column as well as display a separate column from the same table, however, my query doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
    SELECT ProductName, ProductPrice, MAX(ProductPrice) AS MostProfitable
    FROM tblProducts;
```

I receive this error:

> "Your query does not include the specified expression 'ProductName' as part of an aggregate function."

Please Help!

Comment: You must GrouBy ProductPrice

Comment: Thank you, the only problem is that it displays all records, not just the ones with the highest values. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

A simple method to get all the columns to use `ORDER BY` and `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) p.*
FROM tblProducts as p 
ORDER BY p.ProductPrice DESC;
```

Note that `TOP` in MS Access can return more rows if there are ties.  If you want only one row, then include an additional key in the `ORDER BY` to prevent ties:

```
ORDER BY p.ProductPrice DESC, p.ProductName;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any aggregation function just get it like below:

```
SELECT TOP(1) ProductName, ProductPrice
FROM tblProducts
ORDER BY ProductPrice DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I truly appreciate it!

Comment: The only problem now is that it displays all records from that column, not just the ones with the highest value. What do I need to change?

Comment: You mean you want the most expensive product with details?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do, I feel like I'm missing something so obvious.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Mark as answer if answered your question

Comment: @HasanGholamali . . . You are asking the OP to accept your answer, which was revised *after* I provided the correct answer.  Amusing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the question was unclear and you answered the question after read comments in my answer, is this amusing too?

Answer (score 0):

None of the functions of column would work until you GROUP your rows.

That is, your MAX() function will not work because you have not used GROUP.

Here is the SQL that should work:

```
SELECT ProductName, ProductPrice, MAX(ProductPrice) AS MostProfitable
FROM tblProducts GROUP BY ProductName;
```

I would suggest you to add your Product ID in your SQL query and GROUP the query on it. But for the instance, I have grouped your query on ProductName.

Remember, its not professional. Because different products having same name will also be combined to show one MAX value.